# Find variables in base Workspace with partial string match (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, variables, match, partial

I'd like to know how to find a variable in the base MATLAB Workspace by entering only a part of its name. I have a long list of variables & I don't know the exact variable name. Is there a function that compares/matches character order in a list of variable strings?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`who`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html) to obtain a list of all variable names currently in your workspace.  From there, you can use [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html) to do a case **insensitive** [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) lookup to find those variables that match your query.  Something like:

```
namesWorkspace = who;
outStr = regexpi(namesWorkspace, 'nameOfVariable');
ind = ~cellfun('isempty',outStr);
vars = namesWorkspace(ind);
```

`nameOfVariable` is the name or partial name of the variable you are searching for.  `outStr` will provide you with a cell array of elements that is the same size as the total number of variables in your workspace.  If an element in this output cell array is empty, then the corresponding workspace variable wasn't matched.  If it's **non-empty**, then there was a match.  We simply go through this output cell array and determine which locations are **non-empty**, and we use these to index into our workspace names array to retrieve those final variables you want (stored in `vars`).  [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) allows you to iterate over every element in a cell array and apply a function to it.  In this case, we want to check every cell to see if it's empty by using [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html).  Because we want the **opposite**, we need to **invert** the operation, and so `~` is used.

For example, this is my workspace after recently answering a question:

```
names = 

    'O'
    'ans'
    'cellData'
    'idx'
    'names'
    'out'
    'possible_names'
    'possible_surnames'
    'student_information'
```

Let's find those variable names that contain the word `possible`:

```
outStr = regexpi(namesWorkspace, 'possible');
ind = ~cellfun('isempty',outStr);
vars = namesWorkspace(ind)

vars = 

    'possible_names'
    'possible_surnames'
```

## Even simpler

Tip of the hat goes to Sam Roberts for this tip.  You can simply apply the `-regexp` flag and specify the patterns you want to look for:

```
vars = who('-regexp', 'possible')

vars = 

'possible_names'
'possible_surnames'
```

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Comment: Even simpler: you can supply `-regexp` and an expression as input arguments to `who`, and it will only return variables that match. No need for two steps.

Comment: @SamRoberts - Interesting!  Thanks for the tip Sam!  I've edited my post.