# Find variables in Workspace with partial string match adding expressions

Tags: regex, matlab

I have been using the function [`who`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html) as I found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592021/find-variables-in-base-workspace-with-partial-string-match-matlab) for finding variables in the workspace that match a string.

I have been trying without problem:

```
who('-regexp', 'signal');
```

That will return a list of variables containing the string 'signal', such as:

```
'signal'
'signal1'
'signal_RMS'
'signal1_RMS'
```

But I want to know how I can find variables adding exceptions, such as "exclude the variables that ends with '_RMS' ".

I tried including regular expressions as I found in Matlab documentation (regexp), with no luck, and the closer thing I found was something like this:

```
who('-regexp', 'signal(?!_RMS)');
```

But this will only exclude the variables 'signal' that are immediately follow by '_RMS',

```
'signal'
'signal1'
'signal1_RMS'
```

Any hint on how I can handle expressions to find variables such as "start with 'string', do not end up with 'otherstring' " ?

Comment: There are plenty of regex tutorials on the internet. I always found [regexr](http://regexr.com/) helpful.

Comment: So you mean you need `'signal(?!.*_RMS$)'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know who can I find variables adding exceptions, such as "exclude the variables that ends with '_RMS' ".

The `'signal(?!_RMS)'` pattern will find all `signal` substrings not *immediately* followed with `_RMS`. To make sure the strings do not *end* with `_RMS`, you need to allow any 0+ chars in between `signal` and `_RMS` and use the `$` (end-of-string) anchor.

```
'signal(?!.*_RMS$)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFzkfd/1).

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know regex101.com, really useful! this solved my problem